# Enabling device to device firebase push notifications without using cloud functions

Tags: android, firebase

How do I enable device to device push notification on Android using firebase cloud messaging without having to use cloud functions(payment is needed using this). Also,it shouldn't be the method were in the server key is exposed on a client app.

Comment: You'll have to choose some backend other than Cloud Functions and arrange for it to run the code that sends the notification.  There is no escaping that.  Which one is entirely up to you, and recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow (so you'll have to do some research to figure out what's best for your needs).

Comment: You don't have to use Cloud Functions, but you *will* need a trusted environment. Which one you use is totally up to you though.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: ok. While I know the server key shouldn't be included in the app,still what is the most secure way of storing it in the application? Like how web browsers store the passwords?

Comment: Sorry @lanezalbryt, but there is no secure way to do this in the app - otherwise we would have answered that (and probably a long time ago already). The difference between passwords and this key is that a password that is stored in the browser is the user's own information, while this is a key that allows them to target other users.